# Adding a unique_ptr to a class in a vector results in 3x speedup

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector

### Background

I have a large graph (100k nodes), in which each node has to store a bit of information per outgoing edge. Instead of keeping this in a `std::vector<bool>`, I'm using `dynamic_bitset` from Boost 1.58 for the ability to perform bitwise operations. Each node also keeps a pointer to some polymorphic object. A minimal example looks like this,

```
struct Node
{
    std::vector<size_t>     succ;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> succ_flags;
    std::unique_ptr<Object> data;
};
```

### Problem

Consider this simple benchmark program, which creates and destroys a graph:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <memory>

constexpr int N = 50000;

struct Node
{
    std::vector<size_t>     succ;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> succ_flags;
  //std::unique_ptr<int>    data;

    Node(int i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < N; j += i) succ.emplace_back(j);
        succ_flags.resize(succ.size());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) nodes.emplace_back(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Running under the `time` command, a typical result is

```
real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.043s
sys     0m0.010s
```

However, uncommenting the `unique_ptr` line gives something more like

```
real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.003s
```

*Conclusion:* making `Node` heavier by adding a `std::unique_ptr` data member causes `std::vector` to perform over 3x faster!

### Question

Why is this happening, and what sort of gotcha is at work here?

Comment: Are you comparing apples and peaches ? (boost::dynamic_bitset and int)

Comment: I suspect that your first version doesn't have a `noexcept` move.

Comment: @DieterLücking As I read it, he's comparing an apple to an apple plus a peach.

Comment: Your top struct definition doesn't match your bottom one `std::unique_ptr<Object> data;` and `std::unique_ptr<int> data;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding the `unique_ptr` data member makes `Node` a move-only type and the `vector` is forced to move the existing elements when growing its size. In your original example, the `vector` is copying the existing elements because the default move constructor definition is not `noexcept` (because the `dynamic_bitset` move constructor is not `noexcept`).

You should be able to reproduce the quicker result without adding the `unique_ptr` in one of the following two ways:

`reserve` room in the `vector`

```
std::vector<Node> nodes;
nodes.reserve(N);
```

or define your own `noexcept` move constructor for `Node`

```
Node(Node&& other) noexcept
: succ(std::move(other.succ))
, succ_flags(std::move(other.succ_flags))
{}
```

Note that if you provide the above move constructor and `dynamic_bitset`'s move constructor actually throws an exception, `std::terminate` will be called.

Comment: Side question: Why do we need a noexcept move constructor?

Comment: @DieterLücking To maintain the strong exception safety guarantee.

Comment: Thanks T.C., that's exactly it. Your answer does beg two more questions though - why doesn't it have noexcept move (it's just a wrapper for `vector`, and that does) - and secondly, can this behaviour from `vector` be disabled, if I care more about avoiding gotchas than exception safety? (I'm considering asking a follow-up question about this.)

Comment: @PBS 1) Bug. I actually just filed a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11515) about this. 2) No. You can `static_assert` it though.

Comment: So, the compiler generates a default noexcept move constructor *even if* one of the member's move constructor can throw?

Comment: @sbabbi No, the problem here is that the implicitly defined move constructor is `noexcept(false)`, and given that and a copy constructor, `vector` picks the latter when growing its size (because it offers the strong exception safety guarantee). Add the `unique_ptr` data member and the copy constructor is implicitly declared as deleted, leaving the move constructor (that may throw) as the only possible choice for `vector` to use.

Comment: @Praetorian. I understand.. I was under the impression that strong-exception safety was always guaranteed for a vector, but apparently I am wrong. If a move constructor throws there is no way to have the strong exception safety.

Comment: Regarding 2), one workaround is to make a `with_noexcept_move<T>` class which wraps a `T` but with a noexcept move constructor, then define `my_unsafe_vector<T> = std::vector<with_noexcept_move<T>>`.

Comment: @PBS Yeah, that is an option, but anything that accepts only a `vector<T>` will not accept `vector<with_noexcept_move<T>>`, so it might not be a universal solution. Another way to trigger errors if you have throwing moves would be to declare `Node(Node&&) noexcept = default;` Now, if all data members are not nothrow moveable, your code will not compile.